# Redirecting to game ports based on subdomain?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, port

I've been browsing, looking for an answer and there does not seem to be one that works.

Here's the situation:
I have a web server (running Apache) that I only have access to the files for. It hosts all of my websites. I have a VPS that is hosting multiple game servers. They are not the same machine.

My goal is to have 4 subdomains that redirect to each gameserver on a different port ***without*** showing the port. I know this would be possible with SRV records, but the game in question (CS:GO) does not support them.

s1.mydomain.com -> myvpsip:27015, s2.mydomain.com -> myvpsip:27016, etc.

I know this isn't possible by using DNS, but would it be possible editing .htaccess (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715195/how-to-forward-a-subdomain-to-a-new-port-on-the-same-ip-address)) or maybe using a Linux tool that can detect the incoming connection and from what subdomain it came from and redirect it accordingly? I know this has be done (detecting the subdomain that the connection came from).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The game would need to support something like HTTP's Host header, which is unlikely to happen.

Comment: Would this be possible to do with a Linux NAT?

Comment: NAT does not change the fact that there is no way to detect what subdomain is in use. I'd recommend that you read up on TCP/IP networking. Once you do that, everything will be clear.

Comment: http://www.sk89q.com/2012/07/fixing-the-minecraft-session-stealer-exploit/ Is that how this was done?

Comment: The issue described in that link has nothing to do with redirecting things to a different port.

Comment: I meant relating to HTTP Host Header.

Comment: It also has nothing to do with HTTP host headers.

Answer (score 0):

As TCP does not know anything about DNS and hostnames, there is no way to use them to redirect traffic.

The only way you have are different IP's.

Comment: These games are UDP based, but you're still correct.